# The root of the trinomial equation z^n+2*z-t written in terms of FoxH

Tags: equation-solving, special-functions, polynomials

From [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoxH.html), the roots of the general trinomial: $$z^n-z-t=0$$ are written in terms of  **FoxH** special function;

```
 roots = Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n - 1)]^-j + t/(n - 1)*
 FoxH[{{{0, 1}, {0, n/(n - 1)}}, {}}, {{{0, 1}}, {{-1, 1}, {0, 1/(
    n - 1)}}}, t Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n - 1)]^j];

 n = 6; t = N[1/4];

 z^n - z - t /. z -> Table[roots, {j, 0, n - 2}] // Chop

 (* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

I tried manipulate formula to solve equation:$$z^n+2*z-t=0$$,but a failed, after few days.

Could anyone help me?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What about the substitution $z'=-2 z$ and $t'=(-2)^n t$?

Comment: @yarchik. No way: `Eliminate[{z^n + 2 z - t == 0, 2 z == -x}, z]` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Part 1.** This is an extension of the comment of @yarchik. Set

```
p[z_,t_]:=z^n-z-t;
q[z_,t_]:=z^n+2*z-t;
```

I assume that $n>1$ is an integer. Define $b_n \neq 0$ by

```
b[n_]:=2^(n/(n-1))*Exp[I*Pi*n/(n-1)];
```

Then
$$q(-b_n z/2, b_n t) = b_n p(z,t)$$
as one can check using something like

```
Table[q[-b[n]*z/2,b[n]*t]-b[n]*p[z,t],{n,2,20}]//Simplify
```

Therefore, if $(z,t)$ is a root of $p$ then $(-b_nz/2,b_nt)$ is a root of $q$ and conversely, which we will use in Part 2.

**Part 2.** OP has given the following formula for roots of $p$:

```
rootsp[t_,n_]:=Table[Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n-1)]^-j+t/(n-1)*FoxH[{{{0,1},{0,n/(n-1)}},{}},{{{0,1}},{{-1,1},{0,1/(n-1)}}},t Exp[(2 \[Pi] I)/(n-1)]^j],{j,0,n-2}]
```

By part 1, we then get roots of $q$ using

```
rootsq[t_,n_]:=-b[n]/2*rootsp[t/b[n],n];
```

Let us check this in an example:

```
Block[{n=6,t=N[1/4]},
   q[z,t]/.Map[{z->#}&,rootsq[t,n]]]//Chop
(* {0,0,0,0,0} *)
```

Also, unless I have misunderstood the question, `rootsq` is in the form that OP requested, for example `rootsq[t,3]` gives

[image]

Comment: I want general formula terms of **FoxH** solving `z^n+2*z-t;=0` ?

Comment: Amazing answer 1+).Thanks.